# Как задать цвет ячеки в excel по условию?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

Подскажите, не могу сообразить нахожу расхождение в файле

```
 result = df1.loc[df1.ne(df2.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]
             result2 = df2.loc[df2.ne(df1.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]

             datafr = pd.concat([d.reset_index(drop=True) for d in [result, result2]], axis=1)
             datafr.insert(4, " ", "")
             datafr.to_excel(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx', sheet_name='Лист', startrow=2,
                             startcol=0, header=None, index=False)
             wb = load_workbook(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx', read_only=False)
             sheet1 = wb.active
             sheet1.column_dimensions['A'].width = 18
             sheet1.column_dimensions['B'].width = 15
             sheet1.column_dimensions['C'].width = 18
             sheet1.column_dimensions['D'].width = 25
             sheet1.column_dimensions['F'].width = 18
             sheet1.column_dimensions['G'].width = 15
             sheet1.column_dimensions['H'].width = 18
             sheet1.column_dimensions['I'].width = 25

             sheet1['F4'].fill = PatternFill(bgColor="FF0000", fill_type = "solid")
```

нужно пометить ячейки в которых есть расхождения красным цветом которые пустые жёлтым

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я так понимаю нужно условие, но как в фрейме его выполнить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44365839/5741205

Comment: @MaxU да это то, но не подскажете при использование конструкции по ссылке выходит ошибка '`Styler.apply` and `.applymap` are not compatible with non-unique index or columns.' с чем она связана?

Comment: Похоже у вас есть столбцы с одинаковым наименованием - Pandas это не нравится

Comment: @MaxU можете пожалуйста пояснить детально  добавил конструкцию по ссылке  в свой код  styled = (result2.style.applymap(lambda v: 'background-color: %s' % 'green' if v == 'col' else '')) styled.to_excel(f'{self.path}/Результат.xlsx',  engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Лист', startrow=2,
                                 startcol=0, header=None, index=False) но вывод в excel происходит без объединения добавить styled в datafr = pd.concat([d.reset_index(drop=True) for d in [result, styled]], axis=1) выдаёт ошибку AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'reset_index' как можно это обойти?

Comment: можете привести в вопросе __воспроизводимый__  пример данных?